# Make who in all jails

Tags: bash, freebsd, jail

Looking for a script what will show all logged users sorted by FreeBSD jails where they're logged in. So, need run the `who` command in all currently running FreeBSD jails and in the main host too.

I make this:

```
who    #main host
jls | grep -v JID | while read jid ip host path
do
    echo $jid $host
    jexec $jid who
done
```

but the `jexec` need root execution and i'm logging in usually as non-root and make su everytime is painfull...

Is here any other simple way?

Answer (score 0):

The `who` command in FreeBSD knows a `file` argument from where read informations about the logged-in users, the default is `/var/run/utx.active` - and the file is usually world-readable...

Probably will be enough the next script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

while read  jpath
do
    echo JWHO: ${jpath:-$(hostname)}
    who "${jpath}/var/run/utx.active"
done < <( jls -h path | sed '1s:.*::' )
```

example output:

```
JWHO: marvin.example.com
smith              pts/0     7 nov 20:55 (adsl2343-some-another.example.com)
JWHO: /jails/jail1
JWHO: /jails/testjail
root              pts/2     7 nov 20:55 (someother.example.com)
JWHO: /jails/dbjail
```

steps:

- show the path to "root filesystem" for all running jails
- run the who for the `/var/run/utx.active` for the given jail
- skip the header line from the jls, - so the 1st output will be the host.

Maybe someone know much simpler solution, e.g. by sorting the `ps` output or something like...

*Comments*: you usually don't want to use constructions like `command | while read` - the pipe forks new shell and you losing values of the variables set inside of the loop, the `done < <( commands )` is usually better...

Answer (score 0):

You can enable sudo in your system change your script just a little to:

`sudo jexec $jid who`

Then your srcipt can run as normal user.